# Automatically calculate expiry date php

Tags: php, date

In a site I am creating, I want to store member data and in that data I have a start/join date which is easy to get, but I want to automatically calculate the expiry date which I'm having problems with..

Basically all new members will expire on the last day of February each year, so if I join on say 1st Feb 2013 my expiry will be on 28/02/2014, if I join on 1/03/13 or 20/12/13 my expiry will still be on 28/02/2014. ((I don't mind too much about the 1 day that appears on leap years))

Does anyone know how I can work this out - I know it's probably something obvious but I just cant seem to grasp it! :/

(I'll be doing this in php)

Many thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: What if they register in January 2014? Will they expire in February 2015? What is the cut off? 31 December?

Comment: Also, what is the format of the date stored? Is it a simple mysql datetime format? (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Comment: Thanks for your response,

It'll be shown to the user in DD/MM/YYYY but I parse this and store it as simple mysql date format (Y-m-d).

If they register Jan 2014 they should probably expire in 2015 as you say - 31 Dec seems a suitable cut-off.

The user will be able to manually override the date if he wants - but I want to reduce the need to do so for most entries (hence trying to automatically calculate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have (or can get) their registration date in a Unix timestamp format, you could do the following:

```
function calculateExpiry($reg_date)
{
    $next_year = strtotime('+1 year', $reg_date);
    $feb_days = ((($next_year % 4) == 0) && ((($next_year % 100) != 0) || (($next_year % 400) == 0))) ? 29 : 28;
    return strtotime($feb_days.' February '.$next_year);
}
```

This will always return the last day of February for the following year in a Unix timestamp, so you can format it how you like. I think this logic is suitable, see the following use cases:

- Register: `01/01/2013`, Returns: `28/02/2014`
- Register: `09/10/2013`, Returns: `28/02/2014`
- Register: `31/12/2013`, Returns: `28/02/2014`
- Register: `01/01/2014`, Returns: `28/02/2015`

Comment: Picking this as answer because although both this and @abdommon solutions will work BenM responded first. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick too :).

```
function calculate_expiry( $rawDate ) {

    // Convert data into usable timestamp
    $signupDate = strtotime( $signupDate );
    $cutoffYear = date('Y', $signupDate) + 1;

    // Set the expiry to be the last day of Feb (the first day of March -1)
    $expiryDate = new DateTime();
    $expiryDate->setTimestamp( mktime( 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, $cutoffYear ) );
    $expiryDate->sub( new DateInterval('P1D') );

}
```

Comment: I think the cut-off was actually December 31, not February. Looking at yours, anyone signing up on `01/01/2013` will have an expiry of `28/02/2013`?

Comment: Just realised that too. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You could of course just do it in 3 lines... ;) By the way, the `$signupMonth` variable in your answer is no longer needed :)

Comment: Serves me right for doing this while I'm at work haha. Thanks for the second heads-up!

Comment: Ha! Work's time is the best time to get your reputation up ;)

Answer (score -1):

Well, we will get the current signup date by doing...

```
$signup_date = date("m-d-Y"); // or time()
```

And then offset it by another year

```
$expire_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime("+1 year"))
```

Comment: No, that will expire their account in one year from the current date.  That's not what he's asking. Also `date('m-d-Y')` is nothing like `time()`.

Comment: I agree with @BenM here - I know I could do the +1 on year but its the extra logic I'm having trouble with